# I need a GUI for my project in c++

Tags: c#, c++, mfc

I need a GUI system that contain:
a tree list that each item of list linked to a view and when I click on a Item open the view
for next step 
I want to insert to each view some grids.

I see a demo example named :dockpanelsuite http://sourceforge.net/projects/dockpanelsuite/
there is a explorer and multi document
I think that I can change it to my requirment.
but this is in C# and I need something in C++.
if is same sample in MFC ,or I can combine them?
what about performace and stability?
thanks herzl

Comment: You should really accept more answers....!

Comment: Why does this have a c# tag if you only want c++ libraries?

Comment: @herzl shemuelian: You might, but it is far from trivial. The code is in c#, so it can be used from any .Net language. But normal C++ isn't a .Net language. There's a C++/CLI "hybrid" language, but that's not very well known.

Comment: c++/cli is a good language if you want to create an application using Windows Forms or WPF.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Qt is better than MFC for a number of reasons including:

. > 1.It is open source

> 2.It is cross platform. It works on Linux, some mobile devices and
>       Mac
>   OSX. This makes it easier to port
>   programs to other platforms.

```
> 3.Qt is much easier to use and learn that MFC.

> 4.Above all Qt is well documented.
```

Answer (score 8):

use QT. It's comprehensive, has a lot of tutorials in the web out there, is portable and is in C++.

Comment: QT has proven it's use in numerous projects. KDE for example is well known. It is stable, and the performance should be sufficient. But without use case definition, the question of performance can't be answered.

Answer (score 0):

MFC is too big library. Go for win32 if you only want simple GUI

Answer (score 0):

Win32++ as also a nice little library for windows only development.

Answer (score 0):

You could start creating a new MFC SDI App in the App Wizard pick the Visual Studio Project Style, you will need to use the Document/View architecture.

With the generated App you could work you way to have  in the left docking pane a derived ListControl class from CMFCListCtrl.

```
class CMyListCtrl : public CMFCListCtrl
{
    // Your stuff  goes here....
   public:
    DECLARE_MESSAGE_MAP()
    afx_msg void OnLvnItemchanged(NMHDR *pNMHDR, LRESULT *pResult);
}
```

in the implementation file you could handle the click event with something like this..

```
BEGIN_MESSAGE_MAP(CMyListCtrl, CMFCListCtrl)
    ON_NOTIFY_REFLECT(LVN_ITEMCHANGED, &CMyListCtrl::OnLvnItemchanged)

END_MESSAGE_MAP()


void CMyListCtrl::OnLvnItemchanged(NMHDR *pNMHDR, LRESULT *pResult)
{
    LPNMLISTVIEW pNMLV = reinterpret_cast<LPNMLISTVIEW>(pNMHDR);

    POSITION p = GetFirstSelectedItemPosition();
    int nSelected = GetNextSelectedItem(p);
    if (nSelected != -1)
    {
        CString strText = GetItemText(nSelected, 0);

    // we open the document.....
        CMainFrame *pFrame = static_cast<CMainFrame *> (AfxGetMainWnd());
        CWinApp *app = AfxGetApp();
        app->OpenDocumentFile(strText,FALSE);
        pFrame->ShowJobsProperties ();
    }

    *pResult = 0;
}
```